# Function doesn't works when parameter is recieved form another py file

Tags: python

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc
from Software.Syntactic.SyntacticAnalizer import *

sourceFile = "source.txt"
def lex_test(source_File):
    print("ME LLEGO EL PATH")
    lexer = lex.lex()
    parser = yacc.yacc()
    print("CREE INSTANCIAS DE LEX Y YACC")
    print("VERIFICARE QUE NO ESTA VACIO el ----> " + source_File)
    if source_File is not None:
                with open(source_File, 'r') as file:
                    source = file.read()
                    lexer.input(source)
                    parser.parse(source)
                    file.close()
    else:
        print("ESTA VACIO")
    for Tok in lexer:
        print(Tok)


lex_test(sourceFile)
```

This test works fine, but whenever `lex_test()` is called form another file, it doesn't work. I've made sure the parameter is `"source.txt"`. The program fails when it opens the file printing the following:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Comment: Does it not print any error?

Comment: Which file are you calling the function from? And how are you importing the file containing ```lex_test```?

Comment: @VincentM `from Software.Lexical_Analysis.myLexer import *`, I import it from another package

Comment: @PyxlDavon no, thats the only output